# Change a View with a procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is the source of a view , i use this view as the base of a procedure named buscacancelados:

```
 SELECT     NUMERO  FROM dbo.CTRC
 WHERE     (EMITENTE = 504) AND (MONTH(EMISSAODATA) = 3) 
 AND (YEAR(EMISSAODATA) = 2013)
```

This procedure returns the missing numbers in a set

```
alter   proc buscarcancelado  (@emp int) as
 begin
 set nocount on; 
 declare @min int   --- declare the  variavels to be used
 declare @max int
 declare @I int

 IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMP..#TempTable') is not null --  Controls if  exists this table
 begin
        drop table #TempTable -- If exist delete
 end

 create table #TempTable 
              (TempOrderNumber int)-- create a temporary table

 SELECT @min = ( SELECT MIN (numero)                           
                 from controlanum  with (nolock))  -- search the min value of the set

 SELECT @max =  ( SELECT Max (numero)                           
                  from controlanum  with (nolock)) -- search the max value of the set    

 select @I = @min  -- control where begins the while

 while @I <= @max --  finish with the high number
       begin
             insert into #TempTable 
             select @I 
             select @I = @I + 1 
       end 
 select tempordernumber from #TempTable 
 left join controlanum O with (nolock)
 on TempOrderNumber = o.numero where o.numero is null 
 end
```

I want to change the view controlanum with this procedure

```
        create proc filtraperiodo (@emp int,@mes int,@ano int)as
        select numero from ctrc where
        EMITENTE = 504
        and MONTH (EMISSAODATA ) = 3 and YEAR (EMISSAODATA)=2013
```

I want something like this

```
          SELECT @min = ( SELECT MIN (numero) from  filtraperiodo 504,2,2013
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to change the view with that procedure?

Comment: because i need to see distinct intervals and clients  example 504,3,2012 is the client 504 abril 2012

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand what is it that you want

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but as a guess you're looking for a [table-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.100).aspx) that you can pass parameters to. You can think of it as a parameterized view.

Comment: Dude just don't use the view in the first place. Make your sproc use a dynamic query and then have that query change based on what your sproc is looking for. I don't think you really want this sproc making DDL changes.

Comment: I think he wants a sproc that he can pass values to that will build out some dynamic SQL to alter his view. I've done this with a janky make shift way of handling table partitioning.

Comment: @Love2Learn but then why use the view in the first place? Just dynamically alter your sql statement. Adding DDL changes to your sproc based on how you want to call a view seems less effective. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: My scenario was a little different than this. I was populating uniquely named tables with weeks worth of history from another table and then deleting those records from the table. Over time I would drop the oldest table and alter the sproc to union the existing tables of the desired format. It actually works really well for our purposes. In this case I think I was wrong; I think @Pondlife is right; I think he wants a Table-Valued Function.

Answer (score 1):

Create controlanum as a table-valued function instead of a view

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[controlanum]') AND XTYPE IN ('FN', 'IF', 'TF'))
        DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[controlanum]
    GO

    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[controlanum] (
        @emp int
       ,@mes int
       ,@ano int
    )

    RETURNS @numeros TABLE (numero int)

    AS
    BEGIN

      INSERT @numeros
      SELECT numero
        FROM ctrc WITH (NOLOCK)
       WHERE EMITENTE               = @emp
         AND MONTH (EMISSAODATA )   = @mes 
         AND YEAR (EMISSAODATA)     = @ano

      RETURN

    END
    GO
```

Everywhere you reference controlanum, pass it your 3 filter values.  For instance:

```
    --...other code here...

    SELECT @min = MIN(numero)
      FROM dbo.controlanum(@emp, @mes, @ano)

    SELECT @max = MAX(numero)
      FROM dbo.controlanum(@emp, @mes, @ano)

    --...other code here...

    SELECT tempordernumber 
      FROM #TempTable A
      LEFT JOIN dbo.controlanum(@emp, @mes, @ano) O
        ON A.TempOrderNumber <> O.numero
     WHERE O.numero IS NULL
```